# Contain templated data without using templated class

Tags: c++, class, templates, member, class-template

I have the following basic structure:

```
template<typename T>
class A {
    T data;
};

class B {
    A data; // no template parameters
};
```

The data in `class B` can have any template parameters, but I do not want to template `B`, which would be one way to fix the fact that the declaration of `A data` has no parameters.
Is there a way to do this, or must `B` be templated?

Comment: If you are asking for what I think you are asking for, most likely you want `B` to contain any type. Or for `B` to be polymophic. There are a few ways to do this. First use `std::any`, second use `std::variant`. Or use `B` (with a template parameter) but inheriting from a non template base class (aka polymorphic inheritance), this maybe preferred but requires you understand how to do class polymorphism.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not a straight forward way, but you can do it using [`std::any`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any)(which required [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) or later support) as the member of `B` class.

```
#include <any>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
class A {
   T data;
};

// traits for checking template class instance of A
template <typename T> struct is_class_A : public std::false_type {};
template <typename T> struct is_class_A<A<T> > : public std::true_type {};

class B
{
   std::any mData;

public:
   // templates class constructor for any data
   template<typename T> B(T const& data)
      : mData{ data }
   {
      // to restrict B having the data other than A<T> s
      static_assert(is_class_A<T>::value);
   }
};
```

Now you could.

```
A<int> aObject;
B object{ aObject }; // works

// B object2{ 1 };   // compiler error
```

**[See live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/gQQ4ej)**

Answer (score 3):

In your code, `A` is not a class, it is a class template. Therefore, you cannot declare a variable of type `A`, since `A` is not a type. You must provide a template parameter for `data` in `B`:

```
template<typename T>
class B{
    A<T> data;
};

// ---- OR ---- //

class B{
    A<int> data; //int is only an example, you can use any type
};
```